# Aperiodic tiles where the tiles are the same area?

Tags: geometry, tiling

Is there a set of tiles that are [aperiodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_tiling) (with respect to the Euclidean plane) where all the tiles are the same area?

Comment: Sure, take a set of aperiodic [Wang tiles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_tile), and replace the colours with different jigsaw shapes without changing the area.

Comment: Indeed, one can do this with Penrose tiles as well, so long as the boundaries between tiles of different type are modified to change the ratio of their areas.